# Matplotlib Subplot Legends overlap with the Plot when containing many elements

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have subplots with legends that contain a lot of elements. However the legends always overlap with the plots and I can't figure out how to add a spacing between legend and plot or how to make them not overlap automatically in the first place. Is there any option that I would have to use to make them not overlap?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)

for i,axe in enumerate(ax):
    for j in range(10): 
        ax[i].plot(x, np.sin(x)+0.1*j, label="sin(x)")
    ax[i].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=7,ncol=4, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,fontsize = 10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the location of the legend with `ax[i].legend(loc=(0.0,1.04),...)`. The values are the x and y coordinates relative to the size of the axes. This option offers more flexibility than the default `loc` values.

Comment: With a bit of messing around of hspace and this it works well. Thank you!